# Android Studio: Project on multiple computers

Tags: android, collaboration

Is there any tool on Android Studio that helps me open and edit my project from multiple computers, in a way that I can work on it from anywhere and other people, wich I allowed, can also access it? I took a read on GitHub but I understood that the project would go public and that's not the intention.

Comment: In [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) you can create free Private repository.

Comment: What about Subversion?  And you can do a private repository on github for a fee.